# I'm having trouble getting an onclick attribute to run a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger a function by clicking on a link, but this is not working.

This works on a `<button>` or a `<p>` tag or anything else but not on a link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="search()">click me</a>
<button onclick="search()">clickity</button>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function search()
{
    alert("hello");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where in the page is that JS? Is it nested inside any other JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `a` links have a property named `.search`, which isn't a function.

When you assign an inline handler, the properties of the element become accessible as variables, and so the `.search` property/variable is shadowing the global `search()` function.

Just change the name, and it'll work.

```
<a href="#" onclick="mysearch()">click me</a>
```

---

```
function mysearch() {
    alert("hello");
    return false;
}
```

---

Or you could just access the global function directly from the `window` object.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.search()">click me</a>
```

---

It works on the `button` because buttons don't have that property.

Comment: Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement. That properties of elements are added to the scope of inline event handlers is one of the most confusing things IMO.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yep, it's all the confusion of the `with` statement, and without any visible syntax to let you know it's happening.